How to merge specific files from the Selected revision in SVN?
I have made changes in DEV env and must merge them with the Production Branch in Tortoise SVN.
I have Selected a revision from the list of revisions. (EX: i.e.. Revision - 2500 - 7 Files Changed)
Question:

How to Merge only 2 files from the Selected revision from the DEV branch?
Does Tortoise SVN GUI have this support while merging?

Expected Answer:

It could be more helpful if the answers were from both CMD and GUI.

Referred to this Question -  svn merging specific files within revision range, but files lead to conflict!
